# How do an app identify a device in Android

Tags: android

I need to bypass device identification by an app.
I have tried the following method to bypass but did not work:

- Using VPN
- Clear app data
- Reinstall app from playstore
- Reinstall from downloaded apk file
- Change device id (my device is rooted)
- Change google account associated in the device
- Insert different SIM Card

What data reference in the device that an app used?

Comment: So you asking how unknown for us app is identify a device ... this is not valid question here ...

Comment: I have installed an app, let say app A, but certain feature have access limitation per day. I have reached the maximum number of accessing the feature and would like to bypass that. 
I have tried the method mentioned above to avoid the app A from recognizing my device but didn't work.

Comment: Will paying the app developers let you bypass the limitation, by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - only a factory reset will clear those identifiers.

Depends on the android version you are using and considering that everything you mentioned above didn't work, The app is probably using an Android Id or a combination of custom GUID'S.

If it's below android 10, even a factory reset won't necessarily help since it might be using the device IMEI for identification.